# How can I recover data deleted during installation of Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, files, system, delete

## i got a big trouble this is my first day with ubuntu.

while installing ubuntu the participation of the hard disk was deleted and it contains a big project ( i worked on that project about 5 months and i have no copy for it.).
please help me.
is there any way to return my project.
bad starting with ubuntu :'( 
tell me is there any way to return it.
i search for programs to return files but they are only for windows.
and that project for the 08 of October so i need it immediately.

Comment: Were these files located on a Windows partition?

Comment: have you tried this. http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu

Comment: z:/ ( but now i have no partition )

Comment: the total of my disk is 600 go and in computer When i select proprity it shoWs me that it is 600 go.
in devives i only have computer

Comment: the link @g_p gave you is how to recover files from **lost** partitions. Testdisk can still access your files as long as they were not physically overwritten. Therefore **stop using the disk** and work from a live system.

Comment: and remember to *always* back up your big projects..

Answer (score 0):

First STOP USING THE DISK.

Then boot from a live USB. Install testdisk with `sudo apt-get install testdisk`.

Then run it and choose "Recover partition" (not files).

If the files were not overwritten, you might recover them.

Comment: i did not know what i write 
that s my first day